# Video Intelligence Error : gs://samplevideo.mp4 cannot be parsed as CSV

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-automl, video-intelligence-api

I am trying to upload videos to prepare a custom model using AutoML Video Classification.
I have prepared a CSV file. When I upload the CSV file, I get error : 
gs://samplevideo.mp4 cannot be parsed as CSV.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

"gs://samplevideo.mp4" is not a valid object in GCS. You are missing your bucket name. It should be something like "gs://yourbucket/samplevideo.mp4"